# VBA function that return array and automatically fill in the range based on the array dimension

Tags: vba, function

I created a Function where it return an array it is like:
Val(0,0) = "Hello"
Val(1,0) = "World"

So my array is 2 dimensional Array.
If I put my formula in a specific cell let say "=GetData()"
it gives me only 1 value which is the first value in the array.
I know when getting an array I should be select a Range then Enter the formula then press
"CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER", this actually works.

However, I don't know if there is a possibility that by only selecting 1 cell (not a Range) and enter the formula that return an array, I want to automatically fill the cells based on array dimension, so the user don't need to select a Range and press the CTRL+SHIFT+Enter.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the code for your function?

Comment: https://exceloffthegrid.com/dynamic-arrays-and-vba-user-defined-functions-udfs/#Using_UDFs

Answer (score 1):

Excel VBA does not allow to a UDF function to modify the value of another cell. The only thing a UDF is allowed to do is **to return values to the cell/cells it is called from**.

So, what you try doing is not possible.

In order to obtain what you need, **do not use a UDF function**! I mean, do not call it from the worksheet.

If you need a workaround, you can try sheet change `Event`, to target a specific cell (where you change something) and make a code to place the array wherever your code tells it...

An example of doing that, would be the next. You can see that a 1D array can also be used to return in a range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.address(False, False) <> "G1" Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Value = "Go" Then
    Dim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 2) As Variant, arr2 As Variant
     arr(1, 1) = "Hello": arr(1, 2) = "World"
     arr2 = Split("Hello World", " ")
     Target.Offset(, 1).Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
     Target.Offset(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr2) + 1).Value = arr2
  End If
End Sub
```

In order to use it, you must write "Go" on the sheet where the above event exists. I would suggest you to validate the cell as list, supplying `Go,Nothing` and playing with it, will run the code once and not for 'Nothing' list option...

Comment: Thanks Sir :) Highly appreciated your answer. I might need to change my code to work with it.

Comment: @Henjoe: Glad I could help! But, when somebody here gives a helpfull answer, we here tick the code left side  check side check box, ito make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the answer was helpfull. :)

Comment: @Henjoe: I edited the answer and supplied an example of sheet `Change Event` use...

Answer (score 0):

Use the new =FILTER() function in excel. This will return a 1D or 2D array in excel. No VBA required.

Comment: Hello Ian, thank you for your answer.
this is not actually what I want. As @fanedure's answer, what I want to do is not possible. 
Again, thanks for sharing.